# Made Post for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token, but then using it for Home timeline status failed with code 220. Does A standard Twiiter API supports Oauth2.0?

Tags: rest, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

My Post Request to get oauth2 Bearer token is successful but using that token to get status from home timeline is returning following response (I have used correct header 'Authorization'  - Bearer 'bearer token')

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource",
            "code": 220
        }
    ]
}
```

Twitter docs says following about 220 response code

[twitter doc 220 response code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saweg.png)

from below link i've seen standar twitter API supports oauth 2.0
[standard twitter api supports Oauth 2.0](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/authentication-and-authorization)

and there is another section in twitter docs which says [Standard API requires oauth 1.0 , oauth 2 is not mentioned](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the home timeline requires a user's account tokens (since the home timeline only "belongs" to that user), so it requires OAuth 1.0A user context. This will not work with an OAuth 2.0 Bearer token.